# Unable to get influxdb-python client to work

Tags: python, influxdb, influxdb-python

Environment:

- Platform is Ubuntu 16.10.
- influxdb v1.2.0
- influxdb-python v4.0.0

I can connect to the server and perform queries with the influx client, with no problem.

I can perform queries using POSTman.

However, when I try any of the influxdb-python examples, I consistently get the following error:

```
$ python tutorial.py
Create database: example
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tutorial.py", line 68, in <module>
    main(host=args.host, port=args.port)
  File "tutorial.py", line 33, in main
    client.create_database(dbname)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/influxdb-4.0.0-py2.7.egg/influxdb/client.py", line 488, in create_database
    self.query("CREATE DATABASE {0}".format(quote_ident(dbname)))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/influxdb-4.0.0-py2.7.egg/influxdb/client.py", line 339, in query
    expected_response_code=expected_response_code
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/influxdb-4.0.0-py2.7.egg/influxdb/client.py", line 246, in request
    raise e
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=8086): Max retries exceeded with url: /query?q=CREATE+DATABASE+%22example%22&db=example (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f39e6909b10>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11] Resource temporarily unavailable',))
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure that: 1. your influxdb server is running on localhost and on port 8086? 2. it does nto require any authentication, or, that the authentication credentials are correctly supplied to influxdb-python?

Comment: Yes, I am sure.

It is turning out to be an operating system problem. I am able to get the example to work as written on Ubuntu 16.04, and MacOS (Sierra), but not Ubuntu 16.10.

Comment: Okay. Are you sure that you have permission to create a database?